# Specifying keyword arguments with *args and **kws

Tags: python

I've found a behavior in Python that has baffled and irritated me and I was wondering what I got wrong.

I have a function which should take an arbitrary number of arguments and keywords, but in addition should have some default-valued keywords that comprise it's actual interface:

```
def foo(my_keyword0 = None, my_keyword1 = 'default', *args, **kws):
    for argument in args:
        print argument
```

The problem is that if I try calling `foo(1, 2, 3)` I'll only get the printout for 3 and the values 1 and 2 will override my keyword arguments.

On the other hand if I try moving my keywords after the `*args` or after the `**kws` it will cause a syntax error. The only solution I found to the problem was to extract the keyword arguments from `**kws` and setting default values to them:

```
def foo(*args, **kws):
    my_keyword0 = None if 'my_keyword0' not in kws else kws.pop('my_keyword0')
    my_keyword0 = 'default' if 'my_keyword1' not in kws else kws.pop('my_keyword1')
    for argument in args:
        print argument
```

This is horrible both because it forces me to add pointless code and because the function signature becomes harder to understand - you have to actually read the functions code rather than just look at its interface.

What am I missing? Isn't there some better way to do this?

Comment: I wonder, why you are so irritated by what seems so logical. As in first case: you match two first arguments into separate parameters and somehow expect that they would end up also in `*args`.

Comment: Because usually keyword arguments aren't sorted. You could provide any subset of the keyword arguments and leave the rest with default values, and the non-keyword arguments are ordered and required to be placed before any of the keyword ones. In the case of the arbitrary numbers, this separation breaks - I can't place non-keyword arguments without overriding the keyword ones. This feels like it goes against the usual pythonic way of thinking.

Comment: Can't edit - As per my expectation, I expected that all non-keyword arguments would be stored in `*args` and all keyword arguments would be stored in the specified keywords or `**kws`. This seems the most logical behavior to me.

Comment: As I explained in my answer you are making a completely wrong assumption: that an argument with a default value is a keyword argument. Default values are only used when the argument is not provided by the function call, they do *not* modify how you can set the parameter value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function arguments with default values are still positional arguments, and thus the result you see is correct. When you specify a default value for a parameter, you are **not** creating a keyword argument. Default values are simply used when the parameters are not provided by a function call.

```
>>> def some_function(argument="Default"):
...     # argument can be set either using positional parameters or keywords
...     print argument
... 
>>> some_function()    # argument not provided -> uses default value
Default
>>> some_function(5)    # argument provided, uses it
5
>>> some_function(argument=5)    # equivalent to the above one
5
>>> def some_function(argument="Default", *args):
...     print (argument, args)
... 
>>> some_function()   #argument not provided, so uses the default and *args is empty
('Default', ())
>>> some_function(5)   # argument provided, and thus uses it. *args are empty
(5, ())
>>> some_function(5, 1, 2, 3)   # argument provided, and thus uses it. *args not empty
(5, (1, 2, 3))
>>> some_function(1, 2, 3, argument=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: some_function() got multiple values for keyword argument 'argument'
```

Note the last error message: as you can see the `1` got assigned to `argument`, and then python discovered the `keyword` referring to `argument` again, and thus raised an error.
The `*args` are assigned only after assigning all possible positional arguments.

**In python2 there is no way to define a keyword-only value other than using `**kwargs`**. As a workaround you could do something like:

```
def my_function(a,b,c,d,*args, **kwargs):
    default_dict = {
        'my_keyword1': TheDefaultValue,
        'my_keyword2': TheDefaultValue2,
    }
    default_dict.update(kwargs)    #overwrite defaults if user provided them
    if not (set(default_dict) <= set('all', 'the', 'possible', 'keywords')):
        # if you want to do error checking on kwargs, even though at that
        # point why use kwargs at all?
        raise TypeError('Invalid keywords')
    keyword1 = default_dict['keyword1']
    # etc.
```

In python3 you can define keyword-only arguments:

```
def my_function(a,b,c,*args, keyword, only=True): pass
    # ...
```

Note that keyword-only does not imply that it should have a default value.

Comment: +1 Part of the confusion could also arise because you can still set positional parameters as if they were keyword arguments: with `def foo(a=2,b=3):...`, the calls `foo(1,2)` and `foo(b=2, a=1)` should behave identically.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, non-keyword arguments cannot appear after a keyword argument, so the function signature you're trying to use is impossible:

```
foo(my_keyword0="baa", my_keyword1="boo", 1, 2, 3, bar="baz", spam="eggs")  # won't work
```

If you think about this, there are very valid reasons for this restriction (hint: keyword arguments may be presented in any order and positional arguments are... well, positional)

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

> In a function call, **keyword arguments must follow positional
>   arguments.** All the keyword arguments passed must match one of the
>   arguments accepted by the function (e.g. actor is not a valid argument
>   for the parrot function), and their order is not important. This also
>   includes non-optional arguments

`*args` and `**kwargs` contain arguments which *do not match an existing formal parameter*, so once you defined `spam=None` in the argument list, it won't be passed to `**kwargs` anymore:

> When a final formal parameter of the form **name is present, it
>   receives a dictionary (see Mapping Types — dict) containing all
>   keyword arguments **except for those corresponding to a formal
>   parameter.** This may be combined with a formal parameter of the form
>   *name (described in the next subsection) which receives a tuple containing the positional arguments beyond the formal parameter list.
>   (*name must occur before **name.)

The closest approximation to your (impossible) syntax would be something like

```
def foo(my_keyword0=None, my_keyword1='default', numbers=None, **kwargs)
```

which you would use as

```
foo(my_keyword0="bar", my_keyword1="baz", numbers=(1,2,3), spam='eggs')
foo("bar", "baz", numbers=(1,2,3))
foo("bar", "baz", (1,2,3))
foo("bar", "baz", (1,2,3), spam="eggs")
foo(numbers=(1,2,3))
foo(spam="eggs")
etc.
```

which, arguably, may be more readable and less surprising than your original idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(my_keyword0 = None, my_keyword1 = 'default', *args, **kws):
    all_args = [my_keyword0, my_keyword1] + args + kws.values()
    for argument in all_args:
        print argument
```

Comment: Thanks, but my point wasn't in printing all the function arguments. This still doesn't create the separation I was seeking, only a list of all the arguments regardless of weather or not they are keywords.

Comment: I don't understand what you need.